# Entity Framework update issue

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am not sure if it's a bug, but when i add a new view or a new stored procedure to the model it updates all the tables that exist. So my question is should it work like this and if it should how can i add some new procedure without updating the whole model?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "updates all the tables"?

Comment: I added some new columns to one of the tables in sql server and when i added the stored procedure it recreated the table in my model with the new columns. I just wanted to add the stored procedure and keep the old state of the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct functionality when using the "Update Model" function for EntityFramework. It looks at every database object and updates the EF Model to match what it finds in the database. This is, in part, because the designer does not let you specifically choose which tables or view to update, so it verifies any changes in the database. This allows the model to proactively ensure that when it connects to the database there won't be an error based on the database changing.